# Webpack - Copying Files from source to public using CopyWebpackPlugin

Tags: webpack, copy

I have an app in which I'm using Webpack. In this app, I need to copy some static .html files from various directories in my `source` directory to the same hierarchy in the `public` directory. In an attempt to do this, I'm using the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin). At this time, my webpack.config.js file looks like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './source/index.html.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].package.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader','css-loader']        
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
      [ { from: './source/**/*.html', to: './public', force:true } ],
      { copyUnmodified: true }
    )
  ]
};
```

When I run `webpack` from the command line, everything works as I want. The HTML files are successfully copied, including their directories, into the `public` directory. However, when copied, the source directory name is included. For example, if my directory structure is like this:

```
/source
  /dir-1
    /child-a
      index.html
      page.html
    /child-b
      index.html
      contact.html
  /dir-2
    index.html
```

I'm expecting the result of `CopyWebpackPlugin` to output to the following:

**expected:**

```
/public
  /dir-1
    /child-a
      index.html
      page.html
    /child-b
      index.html
      contact.html
  /dir-2
    index.html
```

However, what I'm actually getting is:

**actual:**

```
/public
  /source
    /dir-1
      /child-a
        index.html
        page.html
      /child-b
        index.html
        contact.html
    /dir-2
      index.html
```

Notice how the `source` directory is included in the copy target. I don't understand why this is being included. More importantly, I need to remove it. How do I remove the `source` directory from the path in the target?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [context](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#context) param.

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [{
        context: './source/',
        from: '**/*.html',
        to: './public',
        force: true
    }], {
        copyUnmodified: true
    }
)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, looking at the documentatioin, the "context" option should be in the options object (where copyUnmodified is) and applies to all paterns

https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin

Comment: @Tonio It can be used in both cases. Like array element too. From the docs: `A path that determines how to interpret the from path` and `A path that determines how to interpret the from path, shared for all patterns` https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#context

Comment: Great, that's the solution. Am I stupid or is the CopyWebpackPlugin documentation not so clear?

Comment: @migli documentation isn't very good. I think they would glad to merge docs improvement PR.

Comment: I found the [webpack documentation for the CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#context) quite clear.
It states ao: `If from is a glob, then regardless of the context option, the result will be the structure specified in the from option`. Combined with `To determine the structure from which the found resources will be copied to the destination folder, the context option is used.` this pointed me to the same answer as @StanislavMayorov.

Comment: I found [How to copy files using the Copy Webpack Plugin (Without copying the entire folder structure)](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2021/09/how-to-copy-files-using-the-copy-webpack-plugin-without-copying-the-entire-folder-structure/) article very good at explaining this.

Answer (score 3):

I have used name variable.

```js
patterns: [
    { from: "src/*.svg",    to: '[name].svg'},
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to copy the folder `src/pages/Content/lib` to the folder `build/lib` and keep the original structure with the following configuration:

```js
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: 'src/pages/Content/lib',
          to({ context, absoluteFilename }) {
            return path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'lib', path.relative(context, absoluteFilename));
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
```

I am using webpack 5.23 and copy-webpack-plugin 7

The following example page helped me understand how to configure the plugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#copy-in-new-directory

note that next to from and to, you could add the properties `force: true` and `info: { minimized: true }` to override the previous files and don't execute minimization on these

Comment: Thanks a lot @fredericrous , your answer also helped to solve a issue where webpack compilation step was stuch at 92% progress because the minification process was taking a lot of time
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71450698/9871509