# Angular | Chunk asset optimisation

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, npm-update

This question is a duplicate of [92% chunk asset optimization - webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49184787/92-chunk-asset-optimization-webpack)
. But there was no satisfactory answer for this.

Actually, at local, I use `ng serve` or `nmp start` to start my service and it works fine. But at EC2 instance I need to compress my webpack, so I use `ng build --aot --prod`.

A week ago, everything was working fine but suddenly it started stuck at this line: `92% chunk asset optimization`, I don't know what is going wrong.

That is below:

> ```
> Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.3) is greater than your local
> version (1.6.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
>  11% building modules 10/14 modules 4 active ...src/assets/css/smartadmin-rtl.min.cssNode#moveTo was deprecated. Use Container#append.
>  92% chunk asset optimization
> ```

The possible reason can be that I have developed and tested everything on npm-`6.0.0` and I'm trying to deploy on npm-`5.6.0`.

But When I try to update it using `npm i -g npm to update` it shows:

> ```
> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin/npm -> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin/npx -> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/bin/update -> /home/ubuntu/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/update/bin/update.js
> + to@0.2.9
> + update@0.7.4
> + npm@6.1.0
> updated 3 packages in 15.729s
> ```

and when I try to run `sudo npm i -g npm to update` it shows this:

> ```
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -g git://github.com/jonschlinkert/resolve-file.got /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d9e6c8aa
> npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d9e6c8aa/.git: Permission denied
> npm ERR! 
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-05-24T14_22_49_199Z-debug.log
> ```

I tried searching these error but no help.

Or the other issue can be:

Now my service has started using `WebSocket in Angular`, which was not there a week ago.

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove all the angular dependencies from my machine and reinstall using:

```
sudo apt-get purge npm
sudo apt-get purge node
```

If above commands won't work then type:
    sudo apt-get autoremove

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*Install NPM
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Install latest version of NODE

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then install angular CLI using:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

And then run:

```
npm build --prod
```

And error got removed itself, things are working now.